# TableView external dataSource and Delegate not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that is added programatically below that I want to hook up the delegate and dataSource to an external class. The code looks right however the tableview gets added to the view without getting the cell layout from the external class.

```
let tableView: UITableView = {
    let dataService = ActivityDataService()
    let tb = UITableView()
    tb.tableHeaderView = nil
    tb.tableFooterView = nil
    tb.rowHeight = 50
    tb.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    tb.dataSource = dataService
    tb.delegate = dataService
    tb.register(ProfileActivitySubCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
    return tb
}()
```

Here is the activity service class:

```
class ActivityDataService: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileActivitySubCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the info?

Comment: The UI for the cell, Labels etc

Comment: Where is label ,UI ?? Where have you added your info.?

Comment: You need to register the cell for that table.

Comment: have you register your cell in table view?

Comment: did you try to set breakpoints in tableview methods? they are even called?

Comment: I've just tried to register the cell and it's still not working.

Comment: Tableview gets called and added to the view. It looks to be not referencing the dataService.

Comment: tableview frame ?

Answer (score 0):

When using a `UITableView` thats not in a storyboard or similar you need to register the cell with an identifier.

Depending on your `UITableViewCell` (if its a subclass and/or if you are using nibs or not)

You could use one of these methods:

```
open func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)

open func register(_ cellClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Which is methods of `UITableView`

In your case probably something like this:

`tb.register(ProfileActivitySubCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")`

Comment: The tableview is inside a collection view cell. I can interact with the table view (bounces).

Answer (score 0):

1) **Refactor the table view data source methods to a separate class**

```
  class IceCreamListDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource
    {


      // MARK: - Table view data source

      func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
      {
        return 1
      }

      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
      {
        return 5
      }

      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
      {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IceCreamListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
      }
    }
```

2) **In your controller class do this-:**

```
class IceCreamListViewController: UITableViewController
{
  let dataSource = IceCreamListDataSource()

  // MARK: - View lifecycle

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure: let dataService = ActivityDataService()
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: activityCell, for: indexPath) as! ProfileActivityCell
   cell.tableView.delegate = dataService
   cell.tableView.dataSource = dataService
   return cell

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. As the tableView was inside a collection view I had to use a storyboard object outlet. Finally inside the collection view cell I had to set the delegate and dataSource to the newly created object.

```
cell.tableView.dataSource = dataService
cell.tableView.delegate = dataService
```